# How to set legend labels MPChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to customize legend but not able to do so.My purpose is to give different legend labels.I ma using MPChart library to do so.

```
  ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    mColors.add(R.color.red);
    mColors.add(R.color.text_color_gray);
    mColors.add(R.color.text_color_blue);
    mColors.add(R.color.green);
    mColors.add(R.color.black);
   BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, null);
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("05");
    labels.add("06");
    labels.add("07");
    labels.add("08");
    labels.add("09");
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
  legend.setEnabled(true);
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER);
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
    legend.setColors(mColors);
    legend.setLabels(mLabels);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.animateY(2000);

    LimitLine line = new LimitLine(10f);
    YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.addLimitLine(line);
    yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setVisibleXRange(4);
    mChart.moveViewToX(2);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    mChart.invalidate();
```

Please let me know any solution for this.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise, regarding what your code is doing and what it should do? Are you talking about the labels on the axis?

Comment: @JDenais I want to set legend label not label on axis.Ex-If i have used 4 color then i want to show 4 colors as legend and their corresponding legend value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have 4 legend labels, you need 4 BarDataSet objects.

Having different colours will only group the different colours on the one legend that will be generated.

And you need to pass the colors to the DataSet and it will be mapped with the Legend.

Finally, your DataSets need a label which will be used for the legend. You can specify the label as second parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Can we add legend to LimitLine values when limit line value is Integer not DataSet ?

Answer (score 8):

you can custom your legend like this

```
LegendEntry legendEntryA = new LegendEntry();
legendEntryA.label = "a";
legendEntryA.formColor = Color.GREEN;
```

And add them to legend of the chart

```
legend.setCustom(Arrays.asList(legendEntryA, legendEntryB, legendEntryC, legendEntryD));
```